# How to make the empty rows in the end in the alphabetical order of the MySql table

Tags: mysql

I have a table in the database I want to display the alphabetical data by character If there are some rows are empty and shown at the beginning How to make the empty rows in the end with the alphabetical order

```
SELECT * FROM `user` ORDER BY `Country` ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use expressions in the `ORDER BY` clause; for this situation, I would go with something like:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN `Country` IS NULL OR `Country` = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
   , `Country` ASC
```

Comment: This special solution has solved the problem thanking you